# ServiceModel and f#

Tags: .net, f#, f#-interactive

I am just starting with f# so the question may seem easy for some of you.
so, I am trying to use SyndicationFeed which is located in System.ServiceModel.Syndication namespace. I added following references: System.ServiceModel and System.ServiceModel.Web to the project. The result is that it builds successfully, but when I switch to "F# interactive" window I got an error which reads 
"error FS0039: The namespace 'ServiceModel' is not defined".

I goggled that I should also add reference to FSharp.PowerPack, in order to get rid this error but unfortunately it did not help.
So guys I count on your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

references in script files (and FSI) are added via #r directive

```
#r "System.ServiceModel"
```

you can add parts like below to you source code so it can be both used by fsc and sent to fsi

```
#if INTERACTIVE
#r "System.ServiceModel"
#endif
```

Comment: Thank you, that explains everything :)

Comment: @Jarek - then you should click the hollow check-box next to this answer.